# Can't figure out epoll example in manual

Tags: c, sockets, epoll

Recently, I am study system call `epoll`. I already have basic concept about this topic, but I stuck in example given by manual.

```cpp
/* Code to set up listening socket, 'listen_sock',
              (socket(), bind(), listen()) omitted */

epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
if (epollfd == -1) {
   perror("epoll_create1");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

ev.events = EPOLLIN;
ev.data.fd = listen_sock;
if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listen_sock, &ev) == -1) {
   perror("epoll_ctl: listen_sock");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (;;) {
   nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
   if (nfds == -1) {
       perror("epoll_wait");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   for (n = 0; n < nfds; ++n) {
       if (events[n].data.fd == listen_sock) {
           conn_sock = accept(listen_sock,
                              (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
           if (conn_sock == -1) {
               perror("accept");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
           setnonblocking(conn_sock);
           ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
           ev.data.fd = conn_sock;
           if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, conn_sock,
                       &ev) == -1) {
               perror("epoll_ctl: conn_sock");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
       } else {
           do_use_fd(events[n].data.fd);
       }
   }
}
```

Following is my assumption:

- Above is server code.
- `listen_sock` is file descriptor return from `socket()` in server.

My question is:

1. What did file descriptor `events[n].data.fd` mean? Is server's `fd` or client's?
2. Why if `events[n].data.fd == listen_sock` , then we need to create a new connection?

Comment: It is meant to be used in conjunction with the example similar to that given in [man 3 getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) not as a stand-alone example. See also examples at [**Beej's Guide to Network Programming**](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the man page for `epoll_wait` for details on `struct epoll_event` and its `data` member and to help make sense of the code.

Any given `events[n].data.fd` refers to an `fd` that had some kind of event on it.  It could either be the listening socket, or it could be a client socket if there are active client connections.

If the `fd` with activity *is* the `listen_sock` listening socket, this means that a new client is attempting a connection.  At this point we `accept` the connection and add the new `conn_sock` fd to the set of `epoll`'s `fd`s.

Comment: Can you give me a scenario about enter `else` block? I'm wondering what kind of activity can let the state of fd change except someone trying to connect server.

Comment: Sure the `epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, conn_sock, &ev)` call in the `if` block that handles new connections will _add_ the client connected socket to the set of `fd`s to poll.  On a subsequent call to `epoll_wait`, if there is data available from the client, the code will branch to the `else` statement.

Comment: When client call `connect` is connecting to socket `listen_sock` in server, but why we check the state (data available or not) of `conn_sock` in server?

Comment: That's not how socket programming works.  Please refer to the links offered by other users in comments below your Question for help with socket programming.  You can also check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).

Comment: Thanks your hint, `accept` will create new file descriptor mentioned in reference above. I'll select u as answer!